# How to iterate through an object for below code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

```
**"receipts" : {
  "2020" : {
    "feb" : {
      "report1" : {
        "13-02-2020 18:01:45" : {
          "lat" : "1",
          "lon" : "2",
          "type" : "report",
          "child" : "1",
          "name" : "rep",
          "time" : "42"
        },
      "report2" : {
        "13-02-2020 18:01:45" : {
          "lat" : "1",
          "lon" : "2",
          "type" : "report",
          "child" : "1",
          "name" : "rep",
          "time" : "42"
        },
      },
      }
    }
  }
},**
```

I'm trying to iterate through an object and get the values of report1 and report2.How could I achieve it?

Comment: Show your attempt/s.

Comment: Please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: You need to give an idea of what level of problem we're working with here. Are you JUST trying to iterate over the keys of `['2020']['feb']`? Will you want to iterate over all years and all months, if there are more? What's the actual scope? It's hard to tell based on what you've said here